# Displaying subsets of objects for Many to Many in Django Template

Tags: django, many-to-many

This is what part of my models look like:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharFied()

class Issue(models.Model):
    character = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name="appearances", blank=True, null=True)
```

What I'm trying to do is, when you go to a character's page, it will show all the Issues that Character is in.

This is how my view is setup:

```
def character(request, character_slug):
    character = get_object_or_404(Character, slug=character_slug)            
    return render_to_response('comics2/character_detail.html', {'character': character}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

In the template:

```
{{ character.name }}
```

works

I tried this:

```
class CharactersView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "character_list"
    template_name = "comics2/character_detail.html"    
    def get_queryset(self):
        character = get_object_or_404(Character, slug=self.kwargs['character_slug'])
        return Issue.objects.filter(character=character)
```

But it doesn't work..

But how would I go about in the template displaying all the issues that character has appeared in? For example:

```
Character Name
Issue #1
Issue #2,
etc.
```

I feel this is something very simple, but I'm not getting it. I've scoured the Internet for answers, but can't seem to find things that work. So, let me know what's going and I prefer baby talk and possibly the actual code...thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`following a relationship backwards`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

```
{% for issue in character.appearances.all %}
    {{ issue }}
{% endfor %}
```

since you set a related name, otherwise, `character.issue_set.all` is the default. You can also add the issues to the context by getting the related set in the view.

**full example:**

models.py

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()
    character = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name="appearances", blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        ...
```

views.py

```
def character(request, character_slug):
    character = get_object_or_404(Character, slug=character_slug)
    issues = character.appearances.all()

    context = {'character': character,
               'issues':issues,}                           

    return render_to_response('comics2/character_detail.html', 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

template.html

```
<h1>Appearances of {{ character }}<h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for issue in issues %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ issue.get_absolute_url }}>{{ issue.title }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ issue.volume }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried adding that to the template (included the missing 'for') and it does not display anything. My view for character is still 'def character' as above. I also tried adding {{ issue.title}}, etc. and tried removing the '_set' from issue_set.

Comment: @Aimz because you are using related_name argument, your related set is retrieved by using `character.appearances.all` did that work for you?

Comment: The related name thing worked. Thank you. Next time, I will not add so many related names. It seems I am running into a problem, though, for my Creator section. I will edit up top so the code will show.

Comment: @Aimz If this worked, then please marked it as accepted and ask a new question for your other problem.

Comment: It's the same concept, though, just slightly different.

Comment: It won't let me answer my question but thanks. I'll post a new question.

Comment: @Aimz to mark a question as answered, click the check box under where you can vote up and vote down an answer.